# Sorting a list of items that a user has entered

Tags: c++, windows-phone-7

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of items that a user inputs into my Windows Mobile Device to display from newest to oldest. The way that the old employee has it it just puts them in order the way that you enter them.

Here is where the code reads the list when the CMobileDialog::OnInitDialog();

// Read list

```
for(int i=0; i<list.GetElementCount(); ++i)
{
    const LISTFILE_ENTRY_DATA& data = *(LISTFILE_ENTRY_DATA*)list.GetElement(i);

    int nItem = m_lcList.InsertItem(m_lcList.GetItemCount(), CStringW(CStringA(data.szItemNumber)));
    m_lcList.SetItemText(nItem, 1, CStringW(CStringA(data.szDescription)));

    if(m_Type == LFT_COUNT)
        csText.Format(_T("%.0f"), data.rValue);
    else
        csText.Format(_T("%f"), data.rValue);
    m_lcList.SetItemText(nItem, 2, csText);
}
```

Then this is what happens when you press the View List Button is pushed

```
{
    CPockServerMsg Msg;
    OE_RQ_TYPE& RequestType = *(OE_RQ_TYPE*)Msg.Set(MT_REQUEST, sizeof(OE_RQ_TYPE));
    RequestType = OERQ_RECORDS_LIST;

    if(!m_pRFConnection->SendAndReceive(Msg))
    {
        MessageBox(_T("Error sending Records List request"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }

    if(Msg.m_Type == MT_DATA)
    {
        CViewListDlg dlgViewList;
        dlgViewList.m_pMsg = &Msg;
        dlgViewList.m_Type = LFT_QUANTITY;
        dlgViewList.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(Msg.GetErrorText(), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }
}
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to give your list type a `sort()` method, or switch to `std::list`?

Comment: I am not sure if the program was set up to sort the list. How should I go about it?

Comment: Post your list class, and we'll advise you.

Comment: I am not sure were it is because the list is made as the user scans items or enters them by hand.

Comment: You are trying to do something beyond your ability. You must start with simpler projects, or ask the author of the code for help.

Comment: Well I can not ask the author because he no longer is here. '